# Javascript For Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a screenshot of the "Key-In Data" sheet I am trying to work with:
[key in data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QHsO.png)

And here is my code:

```html
function myFunction(){

var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
{var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B26");
var emailAddress=emailRange.getValues();
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange("E2").setFormula("=B2+C2+D2");

 for (var i=2;i <= 2;i++) {
 var currentCell = activeSheet.getRange (i,5).getValue();
   if(currentCell < 4){
   var message="Product has reached a critical value "
   var subject = "Update on transfusion product (EMERGENCY!!)";}
   else if (currentCell > 6) { 
   var message="Product has reached a normal value"
   var subject = "Update on transfusion product";}
   else 
  {var message="Product has reached a minimum value"
   var subject = "Update on transfusion product";}
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message);
  }

}
}

}
```

What this code does is that it will send an email based on cell E2. The logic is completely fine here and it does not require any changes.

What I do need help with are:

1. Right now, the code is pointing to cell B26 for the email. I need the email in the code instead.
2. I also want to add cell E2's value at the back of the Email message. For example, "Product has reached a critical value of 3".
3. Every time the code is run, a time stamp should be generated at cell A2.
4. After the timestamp is added, I need row 2 of "Key-In Data" sheet to be added to the next available row in the "Summary Data" sheet.

Here is sample test environment:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kA1CH2I0Rho_GcvO_PqsWIAuZMZlK4BFukP-TsUlmyY/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction(){
  try{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ash=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var emailAddress="hardcoded email address";
    ash.getRange('A2').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    ss.getSheetByName('Summary Data').appendRow(ss.getSheetByName('Key-In Data').getRange(2,1,1,ss.getSheetByName('Key-In Data').getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]);
    var vE2=ash.getRange("E2").setFormula("=B2+C2+D2");
    var currentCell = ash.getRange(2,5).getValue();
    if(currentCell < 4){
      var message="Product has reached a critical value " + currentCell;
      var subject = "Update on transfusion product (EMERGENCY!!)";
    }else if (currentCell > 6) { 
      var message="Product has reached a normal value" + currentCell;
      var subject = "Update on transfusion product";
    }else {
      var message="Product has reached a minimum value" + currentCell;
      var subject = "Update on transfusion product";
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e);
    return;
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message); 
  ss.toast("Process Complete")
}
```

Comment: The message is not showing correctly. For now the Email message says: "Product has reached a critical value Range". Everything else is fine.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to add in error handlers such that the data will not be added to the "Summary Data" sheet if the recipient does not receive the email. Just in case, their inbox is full or some other possible issue. Maybe a message box too, to show the entire process is complete too?